# .json in Ionic 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic2

Im working in one application in Ionic 2 and I'm connecting it with node.js server.
For send data (server - Ionic) I send like this:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res){
...
res.end(data);  // data is 0 or 1
}
```

In Ionic, I get the data like this:

```
this.http.post("http://192.168.1.100:8080/post", 'PidoDatosClima' + '_' + this.parameter1)
            .subscribe(data => {
                resp=data.json()
                console.log(resp);
...
```

Where resp is 0 or 1 so... in this example work fine.

My problem is when I need to send more data in my server so... if in "res.end(data)" data is the string "1_2_3"

In Ionic, I get this error:

> EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 1

Somebody know how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you show us what you get when you run your post service?  It may be something in the way the data is being returned, but I don't want to assume.

Comment: You are not receiving json so you might not use json(). Maybe use (<any>data)._body instead (private property)

Comment: Thanks for reply me. Please, could you put one example I have done some test but doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this in your server:

```
var data = { "value" : "1_2_3" };

res.end(JSON.stringify(data));  // Now data is an object with the 1_2_3 value
```

And then in Ionic code:

```
this.http.post("http://192.168.1.100:8080/post", 'PidoDatosClima' + '_' + this.parameter1)
         .map(res => res.json())
         .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data.value);   // Access the value property
...
```